# Google apps Script Learning

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to learn Google apps script but I can not find any clear video. Could you give me some link *basic expression*`Logger.log('Do not take into account the log');`

Thanks

Comment: In the code editor, choose "Help" and then choose "Documentation."  Then search "troubleshooting"

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for asking about where to find reference material.  It's for ***specific*** programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Go here and navigate through every part.This is a pretty very good documentation about app script from google itself.

Logger.log is used to print ,just like printing in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Google Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles) which includes an [Apps Script Video Library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/videos) and example scripts.